# Error:running as root dont use sudo with this script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am sshing to a remote Pc as a root user. When I am trying to run the script with the command "bootstrap.sh", I get the following error.

The bootstrap script needs to install a few packages to your system as an admin, and we will use the 'sudo' command - enter your password to continue
Error: running as root - don't use 'sudo' with this script

This error appears even after I changes the command to 'sudo bootstrap.sh'.

Is there any similar experience on this problem. It looks really strange since I am already a root user.

Any helps will be helpful.

Comment: How is this question at all related to Twitter Bootstrap? Twitter Bootstrap is a specific product.

Comment: The error says, literally: "Don't use 'sudo' with this script." The colloquial meaning of "don't" suggests that you should *not* try `sudo bootstrap.sh`, or at least that you should not be puzzled when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output from the script it may appear it expects to be run as a non-root user with sudo privileges. 
If you tell us where you found the script it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To Bryn

You are right. The solution is to create a new user and then run the script without "sudo".

Hope it can also help the others.